# UIBarButton ignores "setEnabled:YES"

Tags: iphone, nsurlconnection, uibarbuttonitem

I ran into a problem. I can't image why that happens, probably you guys can.

I've created a UIBarButtonItem in IB and linked it correctly. A set the property and synthesized it. At the beginning I set the btn disabled (viewWillAppear).
Then I try to add an entry to my mysql db:

```
NSString *URLStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.justfortestingandsoon.com/example.php?entry=%@", myEntry];
URLStr = [URLStr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSLog(@"URLStr: %@",URLStr);
NSURL *addURL = [NSURL URLWithString:URLStr];
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:addURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:30.0];
            urlConnectionSet = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self];
```

In it's "didReceiveData..." I check which value gets returned:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    NSData *myData;
    myData = data;
    NSString *testString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:myData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"receivedData: %@", testString);
if ([testString isEqualToString:@"ENABLED"]) {
        self.notificationBtnDeactivate.enabled = YES;
    }
...
```

I already debugged it. The line self.notificationBtnDeactivate.enabled = YES; gets called but without any noticable changes on the UI.

Any Ideas?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I've seen "odd" behavior with viewWillAppear method.  Try viewDidLoad or viewDidAppear and see if this makes any difference for you.  If so, this might point to some unexpected behavior in viewWillAppear.  

Just and idea.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But if I leave the viewWillAppear method out, the method "didReceiveData" doesn't enable the button neither. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have two ideas for this:

1. the buttons are not correctly referenced from IB, add some NSAssert and check against nil
2. you doing your UI changes on the wrong thread. Try to use [performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelectorOnMainThread%3awithObject%3awaitUntilDone%3a)